# How to fix wrapping of link tags for small screens

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
<header>
  <!-- header stuff -->
</header>
<main>
  <!-- main stuff -->
</main>
<footer>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x50?text=subheading" class="footer">
  <nav class="footercontent"><a href="/index.html" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Start</a><a href="/reports" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Reports</a><a href="/preferences.go" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Preferences</a><a href="/about.go" target="_top"
      style="padding-right:4px">About</a><a href="/license.go" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">License</a><a href="/admin.go" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Admin</a><a href="/help/help.html" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Help</a>    <a href="/help.pdf" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Pdf</a></nav>
</footer>
```

When I'm viewing this on very small screens (either mobile or resize the browser) The links are not wrapped. Instead I get a scroll bar.

When I add a space manually between every link tag --> `</a><a` becomes `</a> <a` then the wrapping works like a charm.

I'm looking for a css solution or so because I can't really modify the html cause it is generated with a third-party library.

Comment: Have you tried `word-wrap:break-word`?

Comment: I tried word-wrap. It wraps inside the word which is not intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a>` tags are per default inline elements. If inline elements have no dividing element (such as a space or similar elements), the browser doesn't know where to break them.

Just set `display: inline-block;` for your link elements. This way, the browser treats them like inline elements but breaks them like block elements:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x50?text=subheading" class="footer">
  <nav class="footercontent"><a href="/index.html" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Start</a><a href="/reports" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Reports</a><a href="/preferences.go" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Preferences</a><a href="/about.go" target="_top"
      style="padding-right:4px">About</a><a href="/license.go" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">License</a><a href="/admin.go" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Admin</a><a href="http://www.jthink.net/songkong/help/help.html" target="_top"
      style="padding-right:4px">Help</a> <a href="http://www.jthink.net/songkong/help.pdf" target="_top" style="padding-right:4px">Pdf</a></nav>
</footer>
```